# React Native bottom tab is hidden on iPhone X

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, iphone-x

The bottom navigation bar is partially buried at the bottom of the screen in iPhone X and iPhone X Max. It's all fine in other iPhones.

I created the navigation tab using this method:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-bottom-tab-navigator.html

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  CPM: { screen: App1 },
  CPV: { screen: App2 },
  CPC: { screen: App3 },
},

{tabBarOptions: {
  labelStyle: {
  fontSize: 18,
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  paddingBottom: 6,
  paddingTop: 3,
},
style: {
  backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
  height: '6%',
  borderTopWidth: 1,
  borderTopColor: 'grey',
},

}
},
);
```

Expected - The bottom navigation bar will look the same through out iOS devices. 
Actual - In iPhone X and X Max, the navigation bar is buried at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like iPhone X doesn't like it when the tab has styling options that mess with the vertical heights.

I solved it by commenting out the "height: " attribute within the styling section. 
See below the updated settings:

```
{tabBarOptions: {
  labelStyle: {
  fontSize: 18,
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  paddingBottom: 6,
  paddingTop: 3,
},
style: {
  backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
  //height: '6%',
  borderTopWidth: 1,
  borderTopColor: 'grey',
},

}
},
```